# Hierarchical result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                  HIERARCHICAL_RECORDS                |
+----------------+--------------------+----------------+
|     ORG_ID     |        NAME        |      VALUE     |
+----------------+--------------------+----------------+
|       333      |         CC         |       ...      |
|        22      |         MT         |       ...      |
|        22      |         TMP        |       ...      |
|       333      |         TMP        |       ...      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

and a second one with ORGs hierarchy:

```
+---------------------------------+
|           ORGANIZATION          |
+----------------+----------------+
|     ORG_ID     |   PARENT_ID    |
+----------------+----------------+
|         1      |      null      |
|        22      |       1        |
|       333      |       22       |
+---------------------------------+
```

which represent an hierarchy of parameters' values on UI:

```
Org ID# 1
    |
    |----- Org ID# 22
             [MT -> value]
             [TMP -> value]
                |
                |----- Org ID# 333
                        [CC -> value]
                        [MT -> shows value defined in parent #22]
                        [TMP -> redefined value]
```

Here's the thing: if both parent and child have defined some attribute value (e.g. TMP in example), we always should return to the client the value redefined by a child.

So, I would like to have a query that by a given child ID (or maybe set of all the IDs from child to root) will return me records that are defined on the very last level.

E.g., for the example above, if I pass 333 (or set of 1, 22, 333), I would like to have a result of:

```
+----------------+--------------------+----------------+
|     ORG_ID     |        NAME        |      VALUE     |
+----------------+--------------------+----------------+
|       333      |         CC         |       ...      |
|        22      |         MT         |       ...      |
|       333      |         TMP        |       ...      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

where TMP's value from child ORG# 333 will hide one from parent ORG# 22.

So, I need to somehow filter records for parent ORGs and leave only ones actual for child ORGs. At the same time, if a value isn't redefined at a child level, we take the value from it's parent (as with MT defined at ORG# 22 but not redefined at ORG# 333).

How can I do that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long. Since mysql has no "connect by" operator you will struggle to do this in mysql. The only practical solution would be to write a recursive procedure which would populate a temporary table. But it won't be very efficient. Indeed one solution, depending on how frequently the data changes would be to apply the mapping to all the nodes in the database. Whether other solutions (the graph engine, geospatial indexing or alternate schemas) might be more appropriate would depend on the frequency of changes the number of records, the distribution and the cardinality of the data (which you haven't mentioned).